# Is there any note taking software designed for taking notes in school?

Tags: software-recommendation, notes

Hey just wondering if Ubuntu had some great software designed to take notes in school?

Features: Maybe categorize by subject or course #? and Like Keywords or Section titles?

I am aware I can use LibreWord and do Headers for each section and save them to individual folders but seems like Ubuntu might have something better for school.

Answer (score 3):

I quite like FreeMind for taking notes - it's a mind map application.

You can create bubbles for each topic, and put detailed notes in each, decorate the bubbles with icons, and break large clusters out into their own linked files.

FreeMind is written in Java and will work on Windows and OSX as well.

For more prosaic note taking I often find myself using a [TiddlyWiki](http://www.tiddlywiki.com/) - this isn't an Ubuntu app per-se, it's just an HTML page with some clever JavaScript embedded in it. You can take notes and link between topics easily, much like Tomboy. I have an empty TiddlyWiki in my templates directory so that I can create a new one with a right-mouse click any time.

Both these approaches work well on any major operating system - and TiddlyWiki doesn't even need you to install anything.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend Zim, for the sake of brevity, i will not bother to go into details here, instead see the answer I provided to this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63464/note-taking-software-that-can-support-advanced-math-notation)

Answer (score 2):

Well Ubuntu comes preinstalled with Tomboy notes which could be used for this purpose. It supports linking of notes and things like that. I have not really used it much personally, but you might want to try it out, though I feel as if you are looking for a more in-depth note taking software.

Comment: I have used Tomboy quite a bit for note-taking, until I switched to Google Docs for easy export (Tomboy lets you export notes, but only in HTML, one note at a time, and it seems to need to open every single one in your default browser after exporting). Other than that, I actually found it nice to use and liked the Ubuntu One integration. Note that it will likely be taken out of the default installation for 12.04, though you should still be able to get it through the Ubuntu Software Center.

Answer (score 2):

BasKet is an application that might be of interest for you. It's made to be a KDE alternative to Microsft OneNote, if you're familiar with it. You can find it in the repositories, it's name is `basket`.

[image]
*Screenshot of BasKet (taken from [the BasKet home page](https://basket-notepads.github.io/)

Comment: I know this is an old post, but could somebody tell me what the poster means by KDE?

Comment: @LuminousNutria https://kde.org/ KDE is a desktop environment. It is e.g. used by default on Kubuntu, instead of the Gnome desktop that the latest "vanilla" Ubuntu flavour ships with.

Comment: @Exeleration-G could you possibly revise your answer? The sites you linked are no longer available. Some alternative resources I found about BasKet might be https://basket-notepads.github.io/ and https://userbase.kde.org/BasKet

Comment: @ByteCommander, done

Answer (score 1):

[**Org-mode**](http://orgmode.org) is an Emacs mode for note taking and much more. With it you can take notes and take advantage of the normal Emacs commands as well as special features for note taking such as short cuts to make new headings that can be collapsed so that you can overview your notes. You can also make and convert lists, it supports input of advanced maths via LaTeX and you can also export your notes to other formats such as HTML and PDF. Finally you can also tag your notes, such as the subject, and make link between notes (even to particular lines in notes).

It takes a little bit more time to learn Org-mode than Tomboy or Gnote and you need get familiar with Emacs as a whole but after you have [learnt it](http://orgmode.org/guide/index.html) you will found it powerful and efficient.

To install it:

```
sudo apt-get install org-mode org-mode
```