# Recommendation for note app

Tags: 22.04, software-recommendation, android, crossplatform

I'm looking for recommendations for a note app. I'd like it to be cross platform (Android 13 and Ubuntu 22.04), to be able to set reminders, and I'd really like for it to be able to import notes from ColorNote on Android. I have over 4,500 of them, it would be a lot to input manually.

I've been looking at a few lists, such as https://itsfoss.com/note-taking-apps-linux/

My current solution is emulation. Or at least I'm trying to figure out emulation, but I'm having issues with Waydroid and I don't know how to solve them yet.

Edit: Joplin seems perfect, thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Instead of editing your question with the thank you note, you can [accept my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [Joplin](https://joplinapp.org/).
[image]
 <sub>Image source: Joplin Website</sub>

It is [cross platform](https://joplinapp.org/help/install/), and supports synchronization of notes and todos. Moreover, it is free and open source.

While Joplin cloud requires a paid subscription, you can synchronize your notes for free with a free Dropbox/Onedrive account.

It supports Markdown and LaTeX, and also supports inserting photos and documents within the notes.

> import notes from ColorNote on Android

Joplin supports importing notes in [all these](https://discourse.joplinapp.org/t/importing-notes-from-other-notebook-applications/22425) formats. [This post](https://discourse.joplinapp.org/t/importing-from-colornote/13839) covers how to import a note from ColorNote.

---

To install it, run the installation script with the following command (**don't** use sudo):

```
wget -O - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/laurent22/joplin/dev/Joplin_install_and_update.sh | bash
```